# Group Numerical Values by Ranges with Cut

Tags: r, cut, categorical-data, aspect

I've sampled raster ASPECT data which ranges from 0-360 and now I want to group these data into directions (North, South, East, East, etc).

I found the cut function and wanted to try using that, but something seems to not be working. For my breaks, I have 10 ranges, but I keep getting the error that the length of my breaks and labels differs. It says that the length of my breaks is 20 and I'm not sure why. Any advice?

```
ForestType$Aspect<-cut(ForestType$Aspect,
                           breaks= c(c(-2,-1), c(0,22.5),c(22.51,67.5), c(67.51,112.5),c(112.51,157.5), c(157.51,202.5), c(202.51,247.5), c(247.51,292.5),c(292.51,337.5),c(337.51,360)), 
                           labels= c("Flat", "North", "Northeast", "East","Southeast", "South", "Southwest", "West","Northwest", "North"), right=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaks should be continuous. In your case `cut` consider gaps between your vectors (e. g. -1;0) as breaks for which labels are needed. Generally breaks looks like this: `c(-2,-1, 0,22.5, 67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,360)`

Comment: I'm still confused. How do I cut? I tried putting the semi-colons in between vectors but I get an error. If i just put in full line of values, there is a mismatch with my labels again. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewBudsock `cut` make continious intervals. For example, `cut(runif(10), c(0.2, .25, .5, 1))` gives variable with three intervals - (0.2,0.25], (0.25,0.5], (0.5,1]. Values which are outside these intervals become NA.